# Please recommend on Wifi USB adapter for Linux OS

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Please recommend on Wifi USB adapter for Linux OS
I searched Amazon, look like no one says it will support linux
But I am sure some  will.
Please recommend.
thanks.

Comment: I have just ran a quick search on Amazon and found a number of USB wifi dongles which support Linux: http://amzn.to/wKlrq3

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @Anders: Read the link above to get an understanding why this question has been closed, you would have to ask (on) Amazon or the original manufacturers whether they support Linux. There are also hardware lists available for Linux in which you can see whether your device is supported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a source code to support USB WiFi adapter on `drivers/net/usb/*.c` of your kernel source.
There are some model name and  tables.
Go [kernel website](http://www.kernel.org/) and get the kernel source code.